# Assign multiple specified positions of a dataframe to a series

Tags: pandas, dataframe, series

Say I have a dataframe of masks (called `mask`) which tells me where data (called `c1` or `c2`) should go:

```
mask = pd.DataFrame([
                    [0,0,1],
                    [0,0,1],
                    [1,0,0],
                    [1,0,0],
                    [1,1,0],
                    [0,1,0],
                    [1,1,0],
                    [1,0,1],
                    [1,0,1],
                    [0,0,1]],
                    columns = ['C1', 'C2', 'C3'],
                   index = np.arange(0,10))

c1 = ['a','b','c']
c2 = pd.DataFrame([
                  ['a1','a2','a3'],
                  ['b1','b2','b3'],
                  ['c1', 'c2','c3']], columns=['C1','C2','C3'])
```

Each column in `mask` can have several patches of 1's (of a given fixed odd length*, here 3) where the data should go in; call each of these a valid patch. I have two cases of interest:

1. `c1` is the data that should go into all the valid patches of all the columns in `mask`; that is, the desired output is:

```
      pd.DataFrame([[0,    0, 'b'],
                    [0,    0, 'c'],
                    ['a',  0,  0],
                    ['b',  0,  0],
                    ['c', 'a', 0],
                    [0,   'b', 0],
                    ['a', 'c', 0],
                    ['b',  0, 'a'],
                    ['c',  0, 'b'],
                    [0,    0, 'c']],
                    columns = ['C1', 'C2', 'C3'],
                   index = np.arange(0,10))
```

2. the columns from `c2` should go into all the valid patches in the corresponding columns' patches of `mask`; that is, the desired output is:

```
     pd.DataFrame([
                    [0,     0, 'b3'],
                    [0,     0, 'c3'],
                    ['a1',  0,   0],
                    ['b1',  0,   0],
                    ['c1', 'a2', 0],
                    [0,    'b2', 0],
                    ['a1', 'c2', 0],
                    ['b1',  0,  'a3'],
                    ['c1',  0,  'b3'],
                    [0,     0,  'c3']],
                    columns = ['C1', 'C2', 'C3'],
                   index = np.arange(0,10))
```

*A detail: each vertical patch is almost always assured to be a given length N, with N odd (here N=3), but there may be issues at the boundaries; in this case I want the mid-points of each valid patch to be aligned with the mid-point of the data to be inserted (either `c1` or the corresponding column of `c2`). It is assured that the length of each valid patch will be at least (N+1)/2 i.e. mid-point plus at least one half on one of the two sides.

How can I do this without looping over the columns and sequentially finding the locations of all the valid patches in each column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method loops over columns, but uses all vectorized operations so should be fast. This method works if the length of `c2` is odd and all streaks in `mask` are also odd length and >= to the length of `c2`. For groups where those conditions aren't met we'll need to make adjustments.

First redefine c2's index. So it's a symmetric counter around 0. This will allow us to map each Series in c2 to the streaks. For mask transform consecutive 1s into numbers where 0 indicates the middle (since your streaks are always odd) and then we count above and below. This means that a streak of 5 1s will get [NaN, val1, val2, val3, NaN] so that only the middle most values are filled.

The `np.ceil` line is a bit of a hack, but seems to get the logic correct if you have groups that are too small due to the edges.

```
import numpy as np

l = (len(c2)-1)/2
c2.index = np.arange(-l, l+1, 1)
#      C1  C2  C3
#-1.0  a1  a2  a3
# 0.0  b1  b2  b3
# 1.0  c1  c2  c3

df = mask.eq(0).cumsum().where(mask.ne(0))
for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = ((df.groupby(col).cumcount() - (df.groupby(col)[col].transform('size')-1)/2)
                 .where(df[col].notnull()))
    
    # Deal with edges or groups not odd length
    df[col] = np.ceil(df[col])
    
    # Turn counter within group to the value in c2
    df[col] = df[col].map(c2[col]).fillna(0)
```

---

```
print(df)

   C1  C2  C3
0   0   0  b3
1   0   0  c3
2  a1   0   0
3  b1   0   0
4  c1  a2   0
5   0  b2   0
6  a1  c2   0
7  b1   0  a3
8  c1   0  b3
9   0   0  c3
```

---

If you need to map everything with `c1` then very little changes. Turn that into a Series and use that to `map`, instead of the Series from c2.

```
l = (len(c1)-1)/2
s = pd.Series(c1, index=np.arange(-l, l+1, 1))
#-1.0    a
# 0.0    b
# 1.0    c

# All of the same code, just change this very last line within the loop to:
    df[col] = df[col].map(s).fillna(0)
```

Comment: It needs ```np.floor``` instead if the truncation is at the bottom, otherwise this works.

Comment: @MaviPranav ah Yeah I wasn't sure if those needed to be handled differently. You can probably safely apply floor on the bottom half and ceil on the top half if there's only edge concerns.